# Angular 2 Test verify API was called

Tags: unit-testing, angular, mocking, jasmine

I am creating a service in Angular 2 which should call an API url to retrieve its data.

For unit testing I would like to verify that the service actually calls the API. To do this TDD, the service `getPicture` method is currently empty:

```
@Injectable()
export class ImageService {

  getPicture(id: string) {
    //To be implemented later
  }

}
```

My test is as follows:

```
describe('ImageService', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpModule],
      providers: [
        ImageService,
        { provide: XHRBackend, useClass: MockBackend }
      ]
    });
  });

  afterEach(inject([XHRBackend], (mockBackend) => mockBackend.verifyNoPendingRequests()));

  describe('getPicture', () => {

    it('should call picture API', inject([ImageService, XHRBackend], (service: ImageService, mockBackend) => {
      mockBackend.connections.subscribe((connection) => {
          expect(connection.request.url).toBe('localhost/some/url/picture');
      });
      service.getPicture('id');
    }));

  });

});
```

Wherever I look, I see code to deal with any incoming requests. However, I can't find anything that will cause a failed test when no request is made.

I could set some variable (request received) to false, set it true in the subscribe block but this feels clumsy and something that should have a proper implementation already.

How can I verify that the/any http request was made?

Comment: the example in https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/testing/index/MockBackend-class.html worked for me

Comment: The link is broken